# How do I install Linux to a bootable USB stick?

Tags: installation, boot, usb, live-usb, usb-drive

I don't mean to create a bootable Live USB stick that has some persistent storage, I mean to actually install Ubuntu on a USB stick and be able to boot up from this on any computer.

I've managed to create a bootable Live USB stick that isn't a full-blown installation with my own user account and data and everything, and also managed to install Ubuntu on the USB stick without being able to boot up from the USB stick, but I have not managed to accomplish both at the same time so far.

EDIT: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/52687/52726) also only gives me the "managed to install Ubuntu on the USB stick without being able to boot up from the USB stick" problem that I have already encountered :(

EDIT 2: And all the answers about using Unetbootin only give me the "bootable Live USB stick that isn't a full-blown installation" that I have also encountered.

Comment: @mikewhatever Just tried it by installing to a USB from a virtual machine. Now I've got a non-bootable installation of Linux on the USB.

Comment: @Alaa that answer doesn't solve my problem... how can I remove the "This question may already have an answere here:" thing?

Answer (score -1):

use unetboot software.it is availabe for both windows and linux.

Comment: Could you provide more details? Like how do you install the software (is it in the official repository? some other source?) or how to use it?. Most likely it is already described in answer to some other question on this site - an URL pointing there might be nice too.

Answer (score -1):

You can install UNetbootin from the Software Centre, just do a search for its name and click install.

After that you'll need to have the Ubuntu iso file at hand and a USB. Then just follow the instruction in [this tutorial](http://blog.hostonnet.com/how-to-create-bootable-live-usb-ubuntu-with-unetbootin).

Comment: That only creates a Live USB that asks to install Ubuntu onto my computer, not a full-blown Ubuntu installation where I can have my own account and programs and data.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out you can just install Ubuntu to the USB as usual, and then enable Legacy Boot in the BIOS (instead of UEFI) and you can start booting from the USB with a full-blown Ubuntu system.